# File opening error when using StreamReader

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to open a csv file that was selected using the file control.

```
<input type="file" id="fileStoreRoster" style="width:400px;" />
```

In my controller I have this;

```
public ActionResult Ajax_ImportRoster(string fileName)
```

I have some jQuery code that should post the file to the controller;

```
var fileName = $("#fileTimeWindows").val();
$.ajax({
    url: appDomain + '/Maintenance/Ajax_ImportWindows',
    type: "POST",
    data: { fileName: fileName }
});
```

But when I open the file i get an error

> Could not find a part of the path

This only happens on the server when I am trying to access a file on the users machine.

Answer (score 0):

The file is uploaded.. it isn't sent as a `string`.. but a `HttpPostedFile`:

```
public ActionResult Ajax_ImportRoster(HttpPostedFileBase fileStoreRoster) {
    // fileStoreRoster.InputStream is a stream to the file
}
```

Also, remember you need `multipart/form-data` on your form for the file upload to work.

Am I understanding your issue correctly? Your profile appears to assume you're aware of what I've just said already..

Comment: No you understand me correctly.  I think what failed to mention was that this was in an Ajax call.  I'm updating question now

Comment: I'm going to have to rethink the ajax side aren't i?

Comment: You can't upload a file via an ajax form. It's just not possible. Workarounds include using an `iframe`, a Flash object, etc. There are jQuery libraries available that help with this.. but they don't post an ajax form. Look up jquery.fileupload. I've used it in the past and it works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

The html is rendered on the client machine, and therefore the file referenced only exists there. If you wish to work with the file on the server it must be uploaded (posted) to the server first.

Do this by adding a form to your input field, if you don't have one already, submit that form to an action method that takes a parameter of `System.WebHttpPostedFileBase` call it the same as the name attribute of the input field. that parameter will have access to the stream of the uploaded file.